# Implementing 3D vectors in Python: numpy vs x,y,z fields

Tags: python, arrays, class, numpy, vector

I am implementing a 3D Vector class in Python.
My vector has coordinates x, y and z (all floats), and I need to decide how to store this information. I can see at least three options here:

1) Make three separate float fields: self.x, self.y, self.z

```
class Vector:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z
```

2) Make a list, say self.data, with three elements. I may also use a tuple if the objects can be constant.

```
class Vector:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.data = [x,y,z]
```

3) Make a numpy array, say self.data, with three elements.

```
import numpy as np    

class Vector:

  def __init__(self, x, y, z):
    self.data = np.array([x,y,z])
```

For options (2) and (3), I could then implement properties and setters to access the single coordinates

```
@property
def x(self):
  return self.data[0]
```

4) Why not having some redundancy? I could have both a list (or tuple, or numpy array) and separate fields x, y and z.

The class is meant to be used to perform common operations such as vector addition, inner product, cross product, rotation, etc. Performance of these operations needs to be taken into account.

Is there a solution that I should prefer, and why?

Comment: No point in creating a `Vector` class if you can simply create a numpy array `np.array([x,y,z])`. If you have hundreds of vectors you can then also do `np.array([a,x,y,z])` and leverage NumPy broadcasting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43522840/tracking-python-2-7-x-object-attributes-at-class-level-to-quickly-construct-nump explores an alternative of storing the values for all objects in a `class` array, and using `property` to access values for each object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are different aspects to this question and I can give you some hints on how these could be resolved. Note that these are meant as suggestions, you definetly need to see which one you like most.

#### Supporting linear algebra

You mentioned that you want to support linear algebra, such as vector addition (element-wise addition), cross product and inner product. These are avaiable for `numpy.ndarray`s so you could choose different approaches to supporting them:

1. Simply use a `numpy.ndarray` and don't bother about your own class:

   ```
   import numpy as np
   vector1, vector2 = np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([3, 2, 1])
   np.add(vector1, vector2)      # vector addition
   np.cross(vector1, vector2)    # cross product
   np.inner(vector1, vector2)    # inner product
   ```

   There's no builtin vector rotation defined in `numpy` but there are several sources avaiable, for example ["Rotation of 3D vector"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6802577/5393381). So you would need to implement it yourself.
2. You can create a class, independant of _how you store your attributes and provide an `__array__` method. That way you can support (all) numpy functions as if your instances were `numpy.ndarray`s themselves:

   ```
   class VectorArrayInterface(object):
       def __init__(self, x, y, z):
           self.x, self.y, self.z = x, y, z

       def __array__(self, dtype=None):
           if dtype:
               return np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z], dtype=dtype)
           else:
               return np.array([self.x, self.y, self.z])

   vector1, vector2 = VectorArrayInterface(1, 2, 3), VectorArrayInterface(3, 2, 1)
   np.add(vector1, vector2)      # vector addition
   np.cross(vector1, vector2)    # cross product
   np.inner(vector1, vector2)    # inner product
   ```

   This will return the same results as in the first case so you can provide an interface for numpy functions without having a numpy-array. If you have a numpy-array stored in your class the `__array__` method can simply return it so this could be an argument for storing your `x`, `y` and `z` as `numpy.ndarray` internally (because that's basically "for free").
3. You can subclass `np.ndarray`. I won't go into the details here because that's an advanced topic that could easily justify a whole answer by itself. If you really consider this then you should have a look at the official documentation for ["Subclassing ndarray"](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#module-numpy.doc.subclassing). I don't recommend it, I worked on several classes that do subclass `np.ndarray` and there are several "rough egdes" down that path.
4. You can implement the operations you need yourself. That's reinventing the wheel but it's educational and fun - if there's only a handful of them. I wouldn't recommend this for serious production because here as well are several "rough edges" that have been adressed in the numpy functions already. For example overflow or underflow issues, correctness of the functions, ...

   A possible implementation (not including rotation) could look like this (this time with an internally stored list):

   ```
   class VectorList(object):
       def __init__(self, x, y, z):
           self.vec = [x, y, z]

       def __repr__(self):
           return '{self.__class__.__name__}(x={self.vec[0]}, y={self.vec[1]}, z={self.vec[2]})'.format(self=self)

       def __add__(self, other):
           x1, y1, z1 = self.vec
           x2, y2, z2 = other.vec
           return VectorList(x1+x2, y1+y2, z1+z2)

       def crossproduct(self, other):
           x1, y1, z1 = self.vec
           x2, y2, z2 = other.vec
           return VectorList(y1*z2 - z1*y2,
                             z1*x2 - x1*z2,
                             x1*y2 - y1*x1)

       def scalarproduct(self, other):
           x1, y1, z1 = self.vec
           x2, y2, z2 = other.vec
           return x1*x2 + y1*y2 + z1*z2
   ```

   Note: You can implement these can-coded methods and implement the `__array__` method I mentioned earlier. That way you can support any function expecting a `numpy.ndarray` and also have your homegrown methods. These approaches are not exclusive but you will have different results, the methods above return a scalar or a `Vector` but if you go through `__array__` you'll get `numpy.ndarray`s back.
5. Use a library containing a 3D vector. In some sense this is the easiest way in other aspects it could be very complicated. On the plus side an existing class will probably work out of the box and it's probably optimized in terms of performance. On the other hand you need to find an implementation that supports your use-case, you need to read the documentation (or figure out how it works by other means) and you could hit bugs or limitations that turn out to be desatrous for your project. Ah, and you get an additional dependency and you need to check if the license is compatible with your project. Additionally if you copy the implementation (check if the license allows that!) you need to maintain (even if it's just sync'ing) foreign code.

#### Performance

Performance is tricky in this case, the mentioned use-cases are quite simple and each task should be of the order of microseconds - so you should be able to perform several thousand to million operations per second already. Assuming you don't introduce an unnecessary bottleneck! However you can micro-optimize the operations.

Let me start with some general tipps:

- Avoid `numpy.ndarray` <-> `list`/`float` operations. These are costly! If most of the operations use `numpy.ndarray`s you don't want to store your values in a list or as seperate attributes. Likewise if you want to access the individual values of the `Vector` or iterate over these values or perform operations on them as `list` then store them as list or seperate attributes.
- Using `numpy` to operate on three values is relativly inefficient. `numpy.ndarray` is great for big array because it can store the values more efficiently (space) and scales much better than pure-python operations. However these advantages have some overhead that is significant for small arrays (say `length << 100`, that's an educated guess, not a fixed number!). A python solution (I use the one I already presented above) can be much faster than a numpy solution for such small arrays:

  ```
  class VectorArray:
      def __init__(self, x, y, z):
          self.data = np.array([x,y,z])

  # addition: python solution 3 times faster
  %timeit VectorList(1, 2, 3) + VectorList(3, 2, 1)  
  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 9.48 µs per loop
  %timeit VectorArray(1, 2, 3).data + VectorArray(3, 2, 1).data  
  # 10000 loops, best of 3: 35.6 µs per loop

  # cross product: python solution 16 times faster
  v = Vector(1, 2, 3)
  a = np.array([1,2,3])  # using a plain array to avoid the class-overhead
  %timeit v.crossproduct(v)  
  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.27 µs per loop
  %timeit np.cross(a, a)     
  # 10000 loops, best of 3: 84.9 µs per loop

  # inner product: python solution 4 times faster
  %timeit v.scalarproduct(v)  
  # 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 µs per loop
  %timeit np.inner(a, a)      
  # 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.11 µs per loop
  ```

  However like I said these timings are of the order of microseconds so this is is literally micro-optimizing. However if your focus is on optimal performance of **your class** then you can be faster with pure-python and self-implemented functions.

  As soon as you try to do a lot of linear algebra operations you should leverage numpys vectorized operations. Most of these are incompatible with a class such as you describe and a completly different approach might be appropriate: For example a class that stores an array of array-vectors (a multidimensional array) in a way that interfaces correctly with numpys functions! But I think that's out of scope for this answer and wouldn't really answer your question which was limited to a class only storing 3 values.
- I did some benchmarks using the same method with different approaches but that's a bit cheating. In general you shouldn't time one function call, **you should measure the execution time of a program**. In programs a **tiny** speed difference in a function that is called millions of times *can* make a much bigger overall difference than a big speed difference in a method that is only called a few times.... or not! I can only provide timings for functions because you haven't shared your program or use-cases so you **need** to find out which approach works best (correctness and performance) for you.

#### Conclusion

There are several other factors to consider which approach would be best, but these are more "meta"-reasons, not directly related to your program.

- Re-inventing the wheel (implementing the functions yourself) is an opportunity to learn. You need to make sure it works correctly, you can time it and if it's too slow you can try different ways to optimize it. You start thinking about algorithmic complexities, constant factors, correctness, ... instead of thinking about "which function will solve my issue" or "how do I make that numpy-function correctly solve my issue".
- Using NumPy for length-3 arrays is probably like "shooting with cannons at flies" but it is a great opportunity to become more familiar with numpy functions and in the future you'll know more about how NumPy works (vectorization, indexing, broadcasting, ...) even if NumPy wouldn't be a good fit for this question and answer.
- Try different approaches and see how far you get. *I* learned a lot while answering this question and it was fun to try the approaches - compare the results for discrepancies, timing the method calls and evaluating their limitations!

Comment: "If you want speed and don't want to operate on arrays of your vectors you should go with lists". This is true only for the tiniest of arrays; and will never scale to an overall competitive performance. The zen of numpy is to learn to think and code in terms of vectorized operations; this is definitely a time-investment if you are coming from a C-like loopy world; but if you do not feel like making the leap to this different style of thinking, its best to stay away from python altogether.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn Not sure what you want to say (you just cite me) but yes, that first sentence was actually a bit closer to the last sentence "But note that for arrays <= 20-100 elements is generally faster to use pythons lists instead of numpy arrays.". Am I right that you suggest I should make that clearer?

Comment: Sorry; hit enter too soon; hope the edit clarifies my position.

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn You're completly right but this question is about length-3 lists vs. length-3 arrays and as the timings show this is in the regime where lists win (and arrays are not even close, they are 3-20 times slower). If the question were about "arrays of vectors" or length-100 vectors my answer would have been very different. Scaling wasn't part of the question (and wrapping it in a class suggests that scaling isn't intended here).

Comment: Maybe I should ask a different way: Did you downvote because you feel I giving bad advise for **this question** or because I was too general with my statements and I should've explained why it's better in **this case** but possible bad advise in other cases? I'm asking because I want to know how I could improve my answer! :)

Comment: Given that the question was aimed specifically at 3D arrays, I believe that this answer is not misleading. I have added a remark at the end to further clarify this point.

Comment: @MSeifert, I noticed that you removed the use of `map` in the addition, and replaced it with "unpacking" and then adding the components separately. I was wondering if there is a particular reason to prefer one thing over the other. Did you maybe get a faster addition? Or perhaps the unpacking is preferred because it is more readable?

Comment: @Antonio Both, it's faster and more readable. Also I added the scalarproduct and cross-product method and it seemed better to implement them similarly and for cross-product a `map` approach would be really ugly. Please note that I implemented the methods in a way that allows to use arrays as `x`, `y` and `z`. So if you ever want to have vector-arrays you could use `vec = Vector(np.arange(100), np.arange(100), np.arange(100));
vec.scalarproduct(vec)` (just an example) and it would still work. I don't have the time to update the answer today but I'll see if I can clarify it tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1):

Taking into considerations of the use of the class `Vector`, I'd prefer having option-3. Since it yields numpy arrays, the vector operations are relatively easy, intuitive, and fast by using numpy.

```
In [81]: v1 = Vector(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)

In [82]: v2 = Vector(0.0, 1.0, 2.0)

In [83]: v1.data + v2.data
Out[83]: array([1.0, 3.0, 5.0])

In [85]: np.inner(v1.data, v2.data)
Out[85]: 8.0
```

These operations are already well optimized in numpy for performance.

Comment: Right, I guess I'll go for that. I was afraid that the overhead of constructing the `numpy.array` could be more than what I gain from speeding up the operations.

Comment: @Antonio added some `timeit` results. Have a look, please!

Comment: @kmario23 You're timings are seriously flawed. The difference between your timings is just the time it takes to convert a list to an array (8 times). Both timings still have the overhead of numpy operations (and conversions)... I will gladly remove the downvote if you fix the timings because otherwise the answer is good!

Answer (score 1):

If a simple vector type behavior is your aim, definitely stick with the pure numpy solution. There are many reasons for this:

- numpy already has out of the box solutions for all of the basic
  behavior your describe (cross products and more)
- it will be faster by leaps and bounds for arrays of appreciable size (ie, where it
  matters)
- the vectorized / array syntax tends to be a lot more compact
  and expressive, once you get used to it / experienced with it
- and most importantly; the entire numpy/scipy ecosystem is built around
  the interface provided by the ndarray; all libraries speak the common
  language of the ndarray; interfacing with them with your custom
  vector type is entering a world of pain.

Comment: I agree with this take too. However, I have a particular motivation for implementing such a specific class. Whether my motivation is valid is a completely different question (which I may decide to ask to StackOverflow, but then in a different thread).

Comment: I'd be curious about seeing that motivation; I run into those cases every now and then as well, but most of the time I can find a way around that reasoning, and I'm always very glad if I do

Comment: This application doesn't take advantage of array operations.  The arrays are only 3 elements long, and are in separate objects.

Comment: Even if those design choices are a hard given, there can be ways around this; like making the 3 vectors views on a contiguous array.