# Is it possible to vectorize changing an attribute of an object using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a simple object like:

```
class Toy(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = 1
```

If I make 100 unique copies:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

t = Toy()
toys = np.array([deepcopy(t) for x in range(100)])
```

Is it possible to do a numpy operation on this that will change the flag like the following?

```
from random import randint
def deflag(x):
    x.flag = randint(0,9)
    return x
```

If I do a map operation like it works but it's not vectorized as far as I can tell.

```
deflagged = map(deflag, toys)
```

Comment: If you are using a class to just keep a bunch of attributes together (as `deflag` is function and not a method), I'd suggest to use a structured array instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575926/returning-a-vector-of-class-elements-in-numpy/43576406#43576406 explores creating objects like this and accessing attributes.  But that's not the same as modifying existing objects.  Often an object array is little more than a glorified or debased list.